# Alternative for get_server_certificate() with Proxy configured

Tags: ssl, proxy, ssl-certificate

I am trying to get the certificate of target website by doing ssl.get_server_certificate() call. This request times out if proxy is configured on my server (otherwise works fine). Is there a way to pass proxy settings to ssl to get target server's certificate? Or is there any other alternative to get the target website's certificate that honors proxy settings.

Also, target website keeps changing so can't add them in firewall rule to avoid timeout.

```
self.host = 'target-website.com'
self.port = 443
PROXY = (''proxy_ip_addr', 3128)
current_cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((self.host, self.port),
                                              ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_server_certificate` does not support proxies.
But with some code you can just create a tunnel through the proxy using the HTTP CONNECT request, upgrade the tunnel to SSL and then get the certificate:

```
import socket
import ssl

host  = ('target.example.com',443)
proxy = (proxy_ip,proxy_port)

# connect to proxy
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(proxy)

# create tunnel to target
s.send("CONNECT {}:{} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".format(*host))
buf = s.recv(8192)
assert(buf[9:12] == '200') # HTTP/1.1 200 ...

# upgrade socket to ssl - ignore certifcate errors since we only want
# to get the certificate and don't transfer sensitive data
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
cert = ctx.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = host[0]).getpeercert(True)
print(ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(cert))
```

Comment: My proxy server needed authentication for connect. I added that piece of code and I got 200 response. However, when I make the *cert = ctx.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname = host[0]).getpeercert(True)* call, I get 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 678, in getpeercert
    self._check_connected()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 638, in _check_connected
    self.getpeername()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: Sorry, the error that I got was:  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 348, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 609, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 831, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:579)

Comment: *" EOF occurred in violation of protocol"* -  It might be that your proxy decided that  it does not like your (maybe some firewall policy) or that the endpoint has a problem with your request (maybe requires client certificate?). The code as shown works for me. I recommend to check if another client can connect through your proxy to the specific server.